# I get this error even after specifing my routes. Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("register_screen", null) in the _WidgetsAppState

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my Login screen. I am trying to find out what I'm doing wrongly.

This is the error I'm receiving each time I click on "Do not have an Account? Register Here".

> Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("register_screen", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.

Code:

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:wemove_client/deco/formdeco_design.dart';
import 'package:wemove_client/screens/register_screen.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String id = 'login_screen';

  String? email;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 100.0,),
              CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                radius: 70,
                child: Image.asset('images/logo1.png',height: 100,width: 150,),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
              Text('Customer Login',
                style: GoogleFonts.cabin(fontSize: 24.0),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 15.0,),
              Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15,left: 10,right: 10),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    TextField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      autofocus: true,
                      decoration:buildInputDecoration(Icons.email,"Email"),
                      ),
                    SizedBox(height:15.0,),
                    TextField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      autofocus: true,
                      decoration:buildInputDecoration(Icons.lock,"Password"),
                      ),

                    SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
                    RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: ()
                        {
                          print("Logged In");
                        },
                      color: Colors.amber,
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      child: Container(
                        height: 50.0,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text('LOGIN',
                            style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                              fontSize: 18.0,),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                        shape:  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius:  BorderRadius.circular(50.0,),
                            side: BorderSide(color: Colors.amber,width: 2),
                        ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),

              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: ()
                  {
                    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, RegisterScreen.id);
                  },
                  child: Text('Do not have an Account? Register Here.')
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my main.dart where I passed all my routes.

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:wemove_client/screens/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:wemove_client/screens/register_screen.dart';
import 'package:wemove_client/screens/splash_screen.dart';




void main() {
  runApp( MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.amberAccent,
      ),
      initialRoute: SplashScreen.id,
      routes: {
        SplashScreen.id: (context)=>SplashScreen(),
        LoginScreen.id: (context)=>LoginScreen(),
        RegisterScreen.id: (context)=>RegisterScreen(),
      },
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Navigator.pushReplacementNamed` has been deprecated, so each time you use it to move to a next screen, it instead kills the screen. To move to a next screen, use the following:

```js
Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (context) =>
  new RegisterScreen()));
```